# MikTeX 21.6: Entering extended mode: ! I can't write on file `tst.log'

Tags: miktex

After I updated to MiKTeX 21.6 (on Windows 10), it doesn't work with any LaTeX editor, such as Texworks, WinEdt,Texmaker, ...

The typical error information is as follows:

```
Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "tst.tex"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.6)
entering extended mode
! I can't write on file `tst.log'.
Please type another transcript file name:
```

I re-installed the MiKTeX 21.6 several times (always update via the console immediately after re-installing). However, the same problem is still there.

FYI, I installed the MiKTeX 21.6 on another PC on Windows 10. It works well.

I would appreciate it if any one could help me fix this issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where are you running the given command line from? This might be a permission problem - are you sure you have write permissions for the given log file? Do you keep the `tst.log` file opened while running the command?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The error information (given by the command line) was generated by WinEdt (the similar information given by Texmaker was error in .log file). tst.log was unable to be generated or doesn't exist as the compiling process stopped due to the error. I'm not sure regarding the write permission issue. FYI, I install MikTeX for only individual account on a Window 10 laptop and there was not any issue until I updated it to version 21.6. So I'd appreciate it if you would guide me with detailed instructions on how to check if there is a write permission issue.